# PGP Encryption within Azure Durable Function

Tags: python, azure, cryptography, pgp

My goal is to upload a pgp encrypted CSV to an SFTP with an azure durable function / function application. I believe this will require a python library that doesn't depend on a gnupg executable. I have found one thread that mentions a similar problem involving data bricks: [PGP encryption in azure databrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039364/pgp-encryption-in-azure-databrick)

I have only a public key provided in pem format to encrypt the data, not a full key that also contains the private part. I have uploaded multiple versions of the public key into an azure key vault but can't seem to get the correct format to follow the steps outlined in the thread above.

The author suggests using pgpy and a public key stored in a key vault secret (so it must just be a string), here is the first step suggested:

```
import pgpy
from pgpy.constants import PubKeyAlgorithm, KeyFlags, HashAlgorithm, SymmetricKeyAlgorithm, CompressionAlgorithm
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import base64 
import io
 
KEY_PUB = base64.b64decode(publicb64).decode("ascii").lstrip()  
#print(KEY_PUB)

pub_key = pgpy.PGPKey()
pub_key.parse(KEY_PUB)
```

However when loading any version of the key that I have created into public64 I always get the error "Expected: ASCII-armored PGP data" this is if I skip the step where the author assigns the value to the KEY_PUB variable and I just use the key versions that I have stored in the key vault. I have not successfully been able to get the variable KEY_PUB, I have always run into the error "invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (1425) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4"

The only way that I have found to be able to create the KEY_PUB variable as the author has is:
Take my key string from azure and do the following:

```
byte_key = azure_key.encode("utf-8")
encoded_key = base64.b64encode(byte_key).decode("utf-8")
KEY_PUB = base64.b64decode(encoded_key).decode("ascii").lstrip()
```

This fails with the same error when trying to parse the key "Expected: ASCII-armored PGP Data"

I have tried using bash to take the public key that was provided and create an asc version and then uploading that into the keyvault as follows:

```
gpg --import public_key.ask
gpg --export --armor > ascii_armored_key.asc
```

Any help/guidance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated, thanks!